# How to call copy constructor of all base classes for copying most derived class object in diamond inheritance in C++?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, virtual-inheritance, ctor-initializer, private-inheritance

Consider the below code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
     A() {cout << "1";}
     A(const A &obj) {cout << "2";}
};

class B: virtual A
{
public:
    B() {cout << "3";}
    B(const B & obj) {cout<< "4";}
};

class C: virtual A
{
public:
   C() {cout << "5";}
   C(const C & obj) {cout << "6";}
};

class D:B,C
{
public:
    D()  {cout << "7";}
    D(const D & obj) {cout << "8";}
};

int main()
{
   D d1;
   cout << "\n";
   D d(d1);
}
```

The output of the program is below:

```
1357
1358
```

So, for line `D d(d1)` the copy constructor of `D` class is bein called. During inheritance we need to explicitly call copy constructor of base class otherwise only default constructor of base class is called. I understood till here.

**My Problem:**

Now I want to call copy constructor of all base classes during `D d(d1)` execution. For that if I try below
`D(const D & obj) : A(obj), B(obj), C(obj) {cout << "8";}`
Then I get this error:
error: `'class A A::A' is inaccessible within this context`

How to resolve the issue. I want copy constructor of `A`, `B` and `C` when copy constructor of `D` gets called. It might be very small change but I am not getting.

Comment: Those virtual inheritance should be at-least protected. Right now their private. Ex: `class B: virtual protected A`

Comment: As @WhozCraig pointed out, after specifying `public`/`protected` inheritance, now its working: http://ideone.com/yjq3OG

Comment: okay, In c++ classes, by default all inheritances are private, When I made it public like 'class B : virtual public A' and 'class C: virtual public A' then it worked. Thanks a lot @WhozCraig for pointing this out.

Comment: There is no "diamond" "problem".

Answer (score 10):

First, lets change your inheritance as currently it is private:

```
class B : virtual protected A {...};
class C : virtual protected A {...};
```

Now, in your copy constructor, explicitly specify that the copy constructors of `A` and `B` and `C` should be called:

```
class D : protected B, protected C {
    D(const D & obj) : A(obj), B(obj), C(obj) {cout << "8";}
};
```

And the output will be as desired (`2468`).

#### Why?

When we have virtual base classes, they must be initialized **by the most derived class**, otherwise there would be ambiguity concerning whether `B` or `C` for example is responsible for the construction of `A`.

> §12.6.2, (13.1):
>
> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> - First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8),
>   virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a
>   depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of
>   base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the
>   base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.

In particular, if you define a copy constructor, and omit the list of copy constructors it should call, then **the default constructors** will be used.

Comment: I think only change he needed was inheritance accessibility, part 2 was correct as his end (mentioned below code)

Comment: Why should class D know about A? Surely classes B/C should do that - so if in future these two classes implementation changes you do not have to alter D.

Comment: @EdHeal If you override the default copy constructor then I'm afraid you must tell `D` about `A` when there is virtual inheritance.

Comment: Why not get B to call the A's copy constructor? Ditto for C?

Comment: @EdHeal  I'm giving away a little of the answer, but what if B calls to construct A with 1, and C calls to construct A with 2 (and assuming that A has a constructor taking an int, and the 1 vs 2 means something).... which one gets called?  You can only construct A once... so which one happens and which one doesn't?  (Remember, there is only one instance of an A in a D....)

Comment: "_Why should class D know about A?_" Because it is a virtual base class, not a truly indirect base class. The many access paths are indirect for the purpose of access control, but the derived class has a direct semantic link with its virtual base classes, just like it has one with its inherited virtual function. Virtuality of a base class has a lot in common with virtuality of functions.

Answer (score 3):

The way you have inherited your classes, all of them use `private` inheritance.

By changing the inheritance of `B` from `A` and `C` from `A` to be `protected` or `public`, you can resolve the problem.

```
class B : protected virtual A
{
   ...
}

class C : protected virtual A
{
   ...
}
```

or

```
class B : public virtual A
{
   ...
}

class C : public virtual A
{
   ...
}
```

and then update `D`'s copy constructor to:

```
D(const D & obj) : A(obj), B(obj), C(obj) {cout <<"8";}
```

---

**PS** It's baffling to me that the default constructor works even with `private` inheritance.

Comment: @RSahu In the constructor case `D::D()` is not really accessing `A::A()`.  A constructor for `A` must be called, and `D::D()` is not getting any say in which constructor.

Comment: @donkopotamus, Can you please share any reference where it is explained why A::A() is getting called even in private inheritance?

Comment: @donkopotamus "_A constructor for A must be called, and D::D() is not getting any say in which constructor_" what?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution which doesn't require changing the inheritance modifiers of class `B` or `C`:

```
class A
{
public:
     A() {cout << "1";}
     A(const A &obj) {cout << "2";}
};

class B: virtual A
{
public:
    B() {cout << "3";}
    B(const B & obj) {cout<< "4";}
};

class C: virtual A
{
public:
   C() {cout << "5";}
   C(const C & obj) {cout << "6";}
};

class D:B,C,virtual A
{
public:
    D() {cout << "7";}
    D(const D & obj) : A(obj), B(obj), C(obj) {cout << "8";}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding access checking for constructors: from [[class.access]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#6)

> All access controls in Clause [class.access] affect the ability to
>   access a class member name from the declaration of a particular entity
>   ... [ Note : This access also applies to **implicit references to
>   constructors**, conversion functions, and destructors.  — end note]

similarly, [[class.access]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/special#4)

> Special member functions obey the usual access rules. [ Example:
>   Declaring a constructor protected ensures that only derived classes
>   and friends can create objects using it. — end example ]

Regarding base class subobject initialization: from [[class.base.init]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#9)

> In a non-delegating constructor, if a given potentially constructed
>   subobject is not designated by a mem-initializer-id (including the
>   case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the constructor
>   has no ctor-initializer), then ... otherwise, the entity is
>   default-initialized

The lack of any *ctor-initializer* for a base class subobject means that the subobject is default-initialized; from [[dcl.init]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#7)

> To default-initialize an object of type T means: ...
>   The constructor thus selected is called, with an empty argument list,
>   to initialize the object.

So the lack of any base in a *ctor-initializer* is a request for default-initialization for that base, which means calling the default constructor.

The lack of mention of a base class makes no difference; in any case, a constructor has no name and is not named in the *ctor-initializer*, it is referenced either explicitly or implicitly. There is nothing in the standard suggesting that access control should not be performed in such case.

It seems like the constructor, being from an inaccessible base class, cannot be called either way, so your program should not compile.

In any case, you can change the inheritance from private to protected, even add a path to the virtual base class:

```
class D: B, C, virtual A
{
```

This way, the virtual base class `A` is still private, but is accessible to `D`.