# C++ - Why does the default constructor work even in private inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

[The following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703229/how-to-call-copy-constructor-of-all-base-classes-for-copying-most-derived-class) brought this phenomenon to notice where the constructor is being called even in the private mode of inheritance.

I tried it on the Diamond Problem, then made it simpler by [breaking the diamond rule and just keeping virtual inheritance](http://ideone.com/TAkw0M).

Further followed this up by a simple example of a 3-level inheritance which I am showing below (`C` inherited by `B` and `B` inherited by `C` - both in ***private inheritance***) and still the constructor of `A` is being called.

Shouldn't `A()` be `private` and **inaccessible** in `C`?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
     A(){ cout << "1"; }
};

class B:  A
{
public:
    B(){ cout << "2"; }
};

class C:  B
{
public:
   C(){ cout << "3"; }
};


int main()
{
   C c1;
}
```

`Output: 123`
(You can also view the code and output [here](http://ideone.com/yjq3OG))

**P.S**: I have tried it both with the normal case (given here) and with `virtual` inheritance, even with the "Diamond-Problem" - the answer is same every time.

Comment: With private inheritance public and protected members of the base class become private members of the derived class.  However, the base class constructor is called as defined in the base class and not as it was inherited, i.e. it still has public access.  If you want to make the base class constructor inaccessible in the derived class, make it private in the base class.

Comment: @HenriMenke: The answer section is below.

Comment: The question becomes only in the case of virtual and diamond inheritance.

Comment: A is private and inaccessible to C. What's the problem with that? C never tries to access A so all is well.

Comment: @n.m. Making `c1` does use `A()` though. No?

Comment: No, making c1 uses `C()` which uses `B()` which uses `A()`, which is OK because `A` is accessible to `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no virtual inheritance involved, so it's not up to C to construct A. Therefore the constructor for C invokes the constructor for B, which in turn invokes the constructor for A. There is no supposed breach of access specifiers going on.

For the virtual inheritance case, we note that construction of sub-objects that are omitted from the member initialization list is specified by

[[class.base.init/9]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.init#class.base.init-9)

> In a non-delegating constructor, if a given potentially constructed subobject is not designated by a mem-initializer-id (including the case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the constructor has no ctor-initializer), then
>
> - ...
> - ...
> - otherwise, the entity is default-initialized.

So the above clause would seem to indicate the default initialization must happen, with access specifiers supposedly discarded.

What's important to remember is that access specifiers are to limit what programs may refer to inside a class definition, they will not stop the compiler from emitting correct code, such as required by the clause above.

If however, you had attempted to explicitly call the default constructor for the virtual base, it would be ill-formed, [like this](http://ideone.com/TFuvqf):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
     A(){ cout <<"1";}
};
 
class B:  virtual A
{
public:
    B(){cout <<"2";}
};
 
class C:  B
{
public:
   C() : A() {cout<<"3";}
};
 
int main()
{
   C c1;
}
```

Which gives:

```
prog.cpp: In constructor ‘C::C()’:
prog.cpp:18:10: error: ‘class A A::A’ is inaccessible within this context
    C() : A() {cout<<"3";}
          ^
prog.cpp:4:1: note: declared here
 {
 ^
```

Why? Because now it is your program that is trying to breach access explicitly, and not the compiler doing its job.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan - Your question is about the simpler case, so my answer is appropriately about the simpler case. If you want to know about virtual inheritance, make it more than a simple remark.

Comment: Last line is gold!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TalhaIrfan - Happy to help

Comment: Just one confusion! Why does it work when both B and C are virtual?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan - What do you mean? It still won't work even if C inherits virtually. You can't explicitly access A http://ideone.com/MbpbWz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143002/discussion-between-talha-irfan-and-storyteller).

Comment: Access specifiers generally DO prevent the compiler from generating code, that's how we built non-copyable classes before `= delete` was introduced.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I'd say it's the omission of a definition for the copy c'tor that stopped the copying, as opposed to the access specifier. But access specifiers won't stop a compiler from generating code if there's no explicit attempt to access a name. Consider [this proxy object example](http://ideone.com/Ufj90M). The type name isn't accessible,  but C++11 doesn't stop you from defining objects of that type unless you take extra precautions.

Comment: @StoryTeller: One small change to your example: http://ideone.com/NqRZGv

Comment: BTW, the compiler has never had any way to diagnose "omission of a definition for the copy constructor".  It could be defined in another compilation unit, which wouldn't be discovered until link time.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Precisely the step required. But it isn't the plain access specifier to the type that stops it, after all. And linkage is also part of translation, is it not? I'm asking frankly, because I always considered it as such, and would like to know if my view diverges from what the industry thinks.

Comment: "linkage" is the property of a name that determines whether it is visible outside the compilation unit.  Thus the compiler produces it and the linker consumes it.  Considering the linking step as part of overall program build, sure... but although the Standard never requires the steps to be separate, all the rules for diagnostics are written specifically to facilitate independent compilation and a separate link step.  And noncopyable (whether boost or hand-rolled) most certainly resulted in a compile error, due to access specification.  The link error caught copy attempts from inside the class